# Как из класса CMain образуется объект $APPLICATION?

Tags: битрикс

Не могу понять, как из класса CMain образуется объект $APPLICATION?

Как они связаны друг с другом?

Объясните пожалуйста простым примером

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ровно также, как и любой другой объект создается из любого другого класса: с помощью ключевого слова `new`.

В ядре Битрикса это происходит в файле /bitrix/modules/main/include.php в строке:

```
$GLOBALS["APPLICATION"] = new CMain;
```